# Assign Pytest markers to list of parameters

Tags: python, pytest, parametrized-testing

I have two markers setup in my pytest.ini file which looks like

```
[pytest]
markers =
    fast: mark test as fast test
    slow: mark test as slow test
```

And I have a test class which uses parameters like

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('page')
class TestClassFoo:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
    def setup_teardown(self, page):
        name = f'Name: {self.__class__.__name__} {datetime.now()}'
        desc = f'Desc: {self.__class__.__name__} {datetime.now()}'
        yield

        param_names = 'search_criteria_1, search_criteria_2, expected'
        param_values = [
            ('criteria_a', 'criteria_b', 'expected_1'),
            ('criteria_c', '', 'expected_2'),
        ]

        @pytest.mark.parametrize(param_names, param_values)
        def test_foo(self, page, search_criteria_1, search_criteria_2, expected):

            select(search_criteria_1)
            select(search_criteria_2)
            count = get_count()
            assert count >= expected_results[expected]
```

I have tried to add test markers to the individual param_values like

```
param_values = [
    ('criteria_a', 'criteria_b', 'expected_1', 'marks=pytest.mark.slow'),
    ('criteria_c', '', 'expected_2', 'marks=pytest.mark.fast'),
]
@pytest.mark.parametrize(param_names, param_values)
```

which has not worked, along with other similar attempts.  Additionally, it is not exactly what I want.

I am wondering either

1. Can I do something like this, but RANDOMLY assign the 'fast'
   marker to one parameter, and assigning 'slow' to the other parameter values
2. If the above is not possible, what do I need to do to 'hard code' the markers into
   the parameter values as I have been attempting

Thank you for any help!